# SQL set default when no row returned | Data Views

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, automationstudio, data-views

I am running SQL activity which grabs rows from last 2 hours.

However, there will be instances when there is no rows found in last 2 hours and I'd like to set Default values in that case.

**Attempt 1:**

```
SELECT SubscriberID, JobID, ListID, BatchID, (CASE 
            WHEN EXISTS(
                        SELECT 1 
                        FROM _Sent
                        WHERE EventDate >= DateAdd(hh,-2,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
                    ) 
            THEN EventDate
            ELSE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
        END) AS EventDate
FROM _Sent
WHERE EventDate >= DateAdd(hh,-2,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

This seems to not work as master `WHERE` fails to pull 0 records which won't run the `CASE` in SELECT statement.

**Attempt 2:**

```
SELECT CASE 
    WHEN EXISTS(
        SELECT 1 
        FROM _Sent
        WHERE EventDate >= DateAdd(hh,-2,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
    )
    THEN (
        SELECT SubscriberID, JobID, ListID, BatchID, EventDate
        FROM _Sent
        WHERE EventDate >= DateAdd(hh,-2,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
    ) 
    ELSE (
        SELECT 0 AS SubscriberID, 0 AS JobID, 0 AS ListID, 0 AS BatchID, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS EventDate
        FROM _Sent
    )
END
```

> Error: An error occurred while checking the query syntax. Errors: Only
>   one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery
>   is not introduced with EXISTS.

Has anyone managed to set default value using SQL when it returns an empty row?

**Note: The SQL activity is set to Overwrite action.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, with some testing and investigation this is how I have resolved:

```
SELECT SubscriberID, JobID, ListID, BatchID, EventDate
FROM _Sent
WHERE EventDate >= DateAdd(hh,-2,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)

UNION

SELECT 0 AS SubscriberID, 0 AS JobID, 0 AS ListID, 0 AS BatchID, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS EventDate
FROM _Sent
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT 1
                FROM _Sent
                WHERE EventDate >= DateAdd(hh,-2,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))
```

**Explanation:**

- `UNION` brings the results from both tables however, if top table fails to bring in any rows, it will still add the default values to the resulting DE. Also note, I have added `NOT EXISTS` condition to the second table to make sure I don't add default value if row is found in first table.